# Call Jquery dialog and pass a string for message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call JavaScript function and pass a string to it. I tried this way:

```
function dialog(a){              
    // Dialog           
    $(a).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
            } 
        }
    });
```

This is the JSF button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" 
                    onclick="dialog('Dialog Test')">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

When I try to pass a string using this way `onclick="dialog('Dialog Test')"` it's not working. How I can fix this?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
function dialog(a) {
    // Dialog           
    $("<div />", { text: a }).dialog({
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function(event) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Wrap the text in a `<div />` that will contain the dialog text *before* calling `dialog` on it. Previously you were passing jQuery an invalid selector which is why nothing popped up.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4extL/2/

Answer (score 1):

Passing the string to the `dialog()` function is likely working just fine.  What is probably not working is the resulting:

```
$(a)
```

which becomes:

```
$('Dialog Test')
```

As that tells jQuery to look for a CSS selector of `<Test>` objects contained in `<Dialog>` objects which isn't what you meant at all.